# How can I use the gtk3 file chooser with keyboard shortcuts?

Tags: gnome, shortcut-keys, gtk3

Here's the use case.

I want to navigate in the file chooser using only the keyboard. For instance, typing Alt-F, then selecting Open with arrow keys usually brings in the file chooser, but there I block.

How do I switch between column (e.g from Places to the file list)?

How do I switch between Places (From Search and Recently Used to shortcuts, then to bookmarks?)

Comment: Try using the `tab` key.

Comment: @DKBose, tab key is not the answer. First off, it navigates only once over the 3 columns, then it is stuck in the bottom controls, between the file type chooser, the Cancel and the Open button.  Then, it does not always work. For instance, try typing `/`, then `<tab>`. And it does not help navigating between Places, shortcuts and bookmarks either.

Answer (score 2):

https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkFileChooserWidget.html

Under signals there is mention of of default bindings for some of the common use cases

Comment: Hi there, please include a more detail answer, not just a link.

Answer (score 2):

Use up and down arrow keys to scroll through the list.

Use left and right arrow keys to toggle between side-pane and file-list.

Use <kbd>Enter</kbd> to open selected file or folder.

Use <kbd>Esc</kbd> to cancel.